# Running external commands in vim

Tags: vim, wc, vi-mode

It seems that if I run the following inside the `vim`:

`:w !wc -w`

I get the word count of the file. But I don't understand the syntax. How does this work and how would I specify that I want the word count of a paragraph and not of the whole file?

Comment: What are you trying to reach? Counting the amount of words in a paragraph?

Comment: I want to understand the syntax of running external programs inside `vim` and this is just an example. In this specific example I get a word count which is useful feature but I don't know how to use the syntax to get information the way I would need.

Comment: See my comment to Evan's answer re: using VISUAL mode.

Answer (score 5):

When you issue `:w !wc -w`, vim creates a temporary file and then pipes that file to the command following the `!`, or rather it puts your data in a temporary file and asks your shell to execute a command that looks something like the following:

```
 (wc -w) < /tmp/vHhjUPf/2
```

Where that last part is some random folder/filename that vim stores your data in. One interesting thing to note, this command will fail in non-compliant shells like [fish](http://fishshell.com/). This is because fish uses the `(cmd)` syntax for command substitution instead of its traditional use.

Comment: Is there any known workaround for fish shell? It seems like this would be a common bug, but some searching didn't turn up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

To specify a range of data to pass to an external command, type this:

```
:<range>w !<command>
```

For example,

```
:1,5w !wc -w
```

would count the number of words within the range enclosed by lines 1 and 5. Type `:h 10.3` for more information on ranges.

You can also use

```
:<range>!<command>
```

to replace the contents of lines 1 to 5 with the output of the command, which is useful when using external commands to filter text. (e.g. for sorting.) Type `:h !` for more information on filters.

If you wish to run an external command without having Vim pass text to its standard input, run the command like so: `:!command`.

Comment: You can also select a range from visual mode -- ie., if you select a block of text in VISUAL and then run an external command, just that block gets fed to the command's stdin.

Comment: In visual mode, `!` expands to `'<,'>!`. `<` and `>` are marks that mark the start and end of the current/last visual selection, respectively. `'mark` is the syntax for using a mark as part of a range.

Answer (score 1):

The vim command `:w` simply writes to disk the current file.

Using `:w newfilename` you write the current file to a new filename.

The command `:!ls -al` run the external program `ls` with parameters  `-al` and displays the result.

The command you mention (`:w !wc -w`) will (probably) simply write the current file into a pipe to a external commmand (`wc -w`) who in turn will count up the words in current file.

Comment: `!w newfilename` does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @Cratylus that was a typo it should be :w newfilename